# Publish Java to Github package registry with README.md

Tags: java, github, package, publish, readme

I'm publishing my java program to the GitHub package registry, but I can't attach the README.md so I don't have to go into the package and fill in the Description manually. Can you help how to solve this problem?

After building my Java packages from my C++ code,I run command publish to Gitgub Maven registry, and it upload but without description. I need upload my README.md into package description. Is there any way I can do this? Set README.md in build.gradle or maybe it understand other name and I must rename my README.md

## Command for build java

```
./java/gradlew build #--info
```

## Command to publish

```
./java/gradlew publish
```

Comment: Please don't just repost your question if it gets closed or doesn't get enough attention

Comment: @Jorn What's the problem with my post? I have a question that needs an answer, but is this site for this yes?

Comment: Your original question was closed as "Needs details or clarity". If you click that link, it'll explain how you can improve your question so that we might be able to help.